# Taskbar icon is always green in TortoiseHg 2.2 with Mercurial 2.0

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

After installing TortoiseHg 2.2 with Mercurial 2.0 on Windows 7, I see the following problem:

For any new repository, created as per TortoiseHg v2.1.0 documentation, I see that the taskbar icon is always turn green and the directory icons of the new repository is always showing a question mark.

For existing repositories the directory icons are as expected.

Is this a bug in TortoiseHg 2.2?

**Update:**
This is a bug in TortoiseHg 2.2. Please visit https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/1397/overlay-icon-server-hangs-folder-overlays.

Answer (score 0):

@bhadra, could you try the "Update Icons" item under the TortoiseHg context menu and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see my update in the question.